# Cannot find -lphy, -lbtbb files

Tags: compiler-errors, esp32, esp-idf

I am new to VScode and compilation errors. I have installed v5.2 for esp-idf.  However, when I try to compile, I am getting following errors.

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N8z1V.png)

I can locate following files at that location, but VScode doesn't recognize them.

[Files location] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q5Vse.png)

Has anyone encountered this issue or knows how to resolve it?

Thanks for your help in advance!

I have tried setting up a path in cmakelist.txt for the missing files, but still not able to find them.

[CMakeList](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QCtJf.png)